# web service only working sometimes

Tags: c#, sql, web-services

I have developed a web service in C# and tested it through a browser as in...

`To test the operation using the HTTP POST protocol, click the 'Invoke' button.`

When I submit a parameter string through the browser, it works correctly: the operation is updating the database and returning with an operation completed message.

I then wrote a small application which submits an identical parameter string to the web service. This small application returns with a success message however the SQL commands in the of the web service don't seem to have been executed.

Now, in the web-service code, the program execution flow is such that it cannot return an operation success message without going through the SQL part successfully (which it does when the parameter string is entered through the browser). However, the small application sending an identical parameter string to the URL receives a success message without the SQL sequence being executed.

The SQL transaction section has a `START TRANS`, `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` always(?) returning the success or otherwise of the operation.

For some reason the SQL code of the service is not being executed(?) when the parameter is submitted by the program and the normal traps and checks don't seem to have any effect.

Has anyone any experience or ideas on this?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Is this a legacy ASMX service, or a WCF service?